# How to let dialog popup as standalone window?

Tags: qt, qml

I try to put a button and click it will open a dialog, but my dialog  open in `ApplicationWindow`, not as a standalone windows?

**Code**

```py
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    id: root
    Row {
        Button {
            width: root.width
            height: 20
            text: "bn"
            onClicked: myDlg.open()
        }
    }

    Dialog {
        id: myDlg
        title: "Rabbit"
        Label {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "Rabbit"
        }
        standardButtons: Dialog.Ok
        onAccepted: console.log("abc")
    }
}
```

**Effect**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In qml there are different components with the same name in different modules, and that is what happens with Dialog:

- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-dialog.html
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-dialog.html

In the case of the code provided by the OP, the Dialog belonging to the "Qt Quick Control 2" module is being used, and since it inherits from [`Popup`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) then it will be shown as an internal item to the window.

The solution is to use an alias to differentiate:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15 as QQC
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3 as QQD

QQC.ApplicationWindow {
    id: root

    visible: true

    Row {
        QQC.Button {
            width: root.width
            height: 20
            text: "bn"
            onClicked: myDlg.open()
        }
    }

    QQD.Dialog {
        id: myDlg

        title: "Rabbit"
        QQC.Label {
            anchors.fill: parent
            text: "Rabbit"
        }
        standardButtons: QQD.Dialog.Ok
        onAccepted: console.log("abc")
    }
}
```